# Android onPause() not geting called

Tags: java, android

Right now I have a android fragment in which i want to store persistant data onPause.  But Nothing is ever being logged.  Why is onPause() never being called in the fragment?

Fragment:

```
package com.alarm.fragments;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import com.alarm.R;
import com.alarm.models.Alarm;
import com.alarm.sql.Database;

public class AlarmCreateFragment extends Fragment {

    ToggleButton sunday;
    ToggleButton monday;
    ToggleButton tuseday;
    ToggleButton wednesday;
    ToggleButton thursday;
    ToggleButton friday;
    ToggleButton saturday;

    ToggleButton on;
    TimePicker time;
    EditText alarmName;
    TextView alarmTitle;
    private Alarm newAlarm;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        init();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_create_alarm, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("db", "onCreate called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.e("db", "onPause called");
        newAlarm.setHour(getHour());
        newAlarm.setMinute(getMinute());
        newAlarm.setName(getTitle());
        newAlarm.setOn(getOn());
        Database db = new Database(getActivity());
        db.storeAlarm(newAlarm);
    }

    private void init() {
        sunday = (ToggleButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.sunday);
        monday = (ToggleButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.monday);
        tuseday = (ToggleButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.tuseday);
        wednesday = (ToggleButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.wednesday);
        thursday = (ToggleButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.thursday);
        friday = (ToggleButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.friday);
        saturday = (ToggleButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.saturday);
        on = (ToggleButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.alarm_status);
        time = (TimePicker) getView().findViewById(R.id.alarm_time);
        alarmName = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.edit_alarm_name);
        alarmTitle = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.alarm_title);
        newAlarm = new Alarm();
    }

    private int getHour() { // 0-23
        return time.getCurrentHour();
    }

    private int getMinute() {
        return time.getCurrentMinute();
    }

    private String getTitle() {
        return alarmTitle.getText().toString();
    }

    private boolean getOn() {
        return on.isChecked();
    }

    /*
     * Toggle the alarm on or off when toggle button clicked
     */
    public void changeStatus(View view) {
        boolean on = getOn();
        if (on) {
            newAlarm.setOn(true);
        } else {
            newAlarm.setOn(false);
        }
    }

}
```

Activity:

```
package com.alarm.activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.alarm.R;

public class AlarmCreateActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.frag_create_alarm);
    }
}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.  I just want to know why the fragments onPause() method isn't being called.  (the log never happens)

Comment: What are you doing to expect the onPause to be called?

Comment: I have a parent activity declared in the manifest and I tried both navigating up that way and by using the back button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this.

> The lifecycle of the activity in which the fragment lives directly affects the lifecycle of the fragment, such that each lifecycle callback for the activity results in a similar callback for each fragment. For example, when the activity receives onPause(), each fragment in the activity receives onPause().

I can search this link. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle